# Pass attribute value to other page in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Actually, i'm working on php, i want to pass span class value to another page it is possible ?. i want pass this [ 1)category_Hdng 2)inrHdng2 ] class value to this page category and product input text-- get_quote.php

Here my Html code:file name:pos-455.php.

```
<div class="innerHdng">
 <span class ="category_Hdng" style="display:none">POINT OF SALE (POS) 
 SYSTEM</span>
 <span class="inrHdng2" style="display:none">pos-455</span>
</div>
```

Here get_quote.php

```
<form action="mini_quote_enquiry.php" method="post" class="frm_mini" >

    <div class="mini_width_left">

        <input type="text" name="category" id="category" disabled />     
    </div>

    <div class="mini_width_right">

     <input type="text" name="product" id="product" disabled />       
    </div>

    <div class="mini_width_bottom">      
      <input name="submit" id="quick_btnsubmit" class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Send Enquiry" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Jquery code: sampe page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var category_name = $( ".category_Hdng" ).text();
  var product_name = $( ".inrHdng2" ).text();
    $('#category').val(category_name); 
  $('#product').val(product_name); 
  $("#category").attr("placeholder", category_name);
    $("#category").attr(disabled);

        $("#product").attr("placeholder", product_name);
    $("#product").attr(disabled);


});
</script>
```

Comment: To pass data between page you can use GET or POST Method. For example in your form you pass your data via POST method to mini_quote_enquiry.php. You can insert the value of your span class into an hidden input via jQuery and retrieve it via POST in your page mini_quote_enquiry.php

Comment: Yon can also store values in [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and use it at any page.

Answer (score 0):

$POST[] or $POST['xx']

xx is your input name

Answer (score 0):

add this code on "mini_quote_enquiry.php" file

```
<?php
$category=$_POST['category'];
$product=$_POST['product'];
echo  $category;
echo "<br>";
echo  $product;
?>
```

Here POST will receive the data from your HTML file and echo displays the received data